# Can you serve static HTML pages from Pyramid?

Tags: python, html, pyramid

I have a Pyramid app using Mako templates and am wondering if it is possible to serve static HTML pages within the app?

For the project I'm working on, we want to have relatively static pages for the public "front-facing" bits, and then the application will dynamically serve the meat of the site. We would like one of our internal users to be able to edit some of the HTML content for these pages to update them.

I have my static folder that I'm serving CSS and scripts from, but that doesn't seem to really fit what I'd like to do.  I could create views for the pages and basically have static content in the mako templates themselves but I think the application would need to be restarted if someone were to update the template for the changes to appear?  Maybe that's not the case?

Long term I would probably do something like store the content in a db and have it dynamically served but that's outside of the scope at this time.

Is there a reasonable way to accomplish this or should I not even bother and set up the public pages as just a regular static HTML site and just link to my app altogether?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serve static html from Pyramid by using views that return pre-fabricated responses. You'll have a more fun time doing it though by just having your web server serve static html if it finds it, otherwise proxying the request to your Pyramid app.

Comment: That's what I thought; I could have the views return templates that have static text or just have the static content in the view itself.  But that doesn't let users manually edit the content and update it as far as I know.  

I think going the route of a mixed application / static pages is what I'll do.